# C# Удалить элемент в копии List, не изменяя оригинальный List

Tags: c#, list

подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу удалить элемент в List#2, который копирую с List#1, но чтобы List№1 не изменялся?
Моя задача, удалить один элемент из списка. Для этого я делаю копию оригинального, и удаляю в копии, чтобы в следующий раз все элементы снова были целы. Но каждый раз, в оригинальном списке стает на один элемент меньше, почему так?

```
// List allelements {"Alina","Marina","Artem","Anton")


public async Task giver(name, List<string> allelements)
    {
        var copylist = allelements;
        copylist.Remove(name);
        var k = copylist.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(2);
        string b = "";
        foreach (string str in copylist)
        {
            b += str + " ";
        }
        // После этого в каждом следующем вызове в allelements удаляется элемент name. 
        // Почему удаление не производится только в copylist?
    }


await giver(name, allelements);
```

Comment: Зачем вам тут async, если в методе ни одного await?

Comment: Это 10% кусочек от всего метода, но спасибо за переживания)

Comment: Ок, тогда просто совет, называйте методы с большой буквы, так принято в C#. А асинхронным методам в конец названия добавляйте суффикс `...Async`, так рекомендует делать Microsoft. `GiverAsync()`

Comment: Супер, спасибо большое! Буду пользоваться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы делаете не копию списка, а копию ссылки на все тот же лист. Создать новый можно, например, так:

```
var copylist = new List<string>(allelements);
```

Почитайте про разницу между типами значений и ссылочными типами. У них несколько разный смысл у оператора присваивания.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Перед этим пробовал
List<string> copylist = new List<string>();
copylist = allelements;
И подумал, что это одинаково... Буду разбираться, спасибо!